# Wrong alloc size or wrong usage of the free-method?

Tags: c, malloc

I have structures and I allocate memory for it:

```
TRANSITION *transitions = malloc(sizeof(TRANSITION *));
```

And I add transitions to it in another part of the program so I realloc memory:

```
TRANSITION *transitions = source->transitions;
transitions = realloc(transitions, (numberTransitions + 1) * sizeof(TRANSITION *));
```

And I have a method that wants to free the memory:

```
free(transitions);
```

When I call the free method I get:

```
"Aborted (core dumped)"
```

What is wrong?

The whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct STATE STATE;
typedef struct TRANSITION TRANSITION;

struct STATE
{
    char name[4];
    bool initial_state;
    bool final_state;
    TRANSITION *transitions;
    int numberTransitions;
};

struct TRANSITION
{
    char c;
    STATE *destination;
};

STATE *create_state(char *name, bool is_initial, bool is_final);
void add_transition(STATE *source, char sign, STATE *dest);
void destroy_state(STATE **pp_state);

int main(void)
{
  STATE *state0 = create_state("S'0", true, false);
STATE *state1 = create_state("S'1", false, false);
STATE *state2 = create_state("S'2", false, true);
STATE *zero_state = create_state("0", false, false);

add_transition(state0, 'a', state1);
add_transition(state0, 'b', zero_state);

add_transition(zero_state, 'a', zero_state);
add_transition(zero_state, 'b', zero_state);

add_transition(state1, 'a', state1);
add_transition(state1, 'b', state2);

add_transition(state2, 'a', state1);
add_transition(state2, 'b', state2);
destroy_state(&state0);
}

STATE *create_state(char *name, bool is_initial, bool is_final)
{
    STATE *state = malloc(sizeof(STATE *));
    strcpy(state->name, name);
    state->initial_state = is_initial;
    state->final_state = is_final;
    state->transitions = NULL;
    state->numberTransitions = 0;
    return state;
}

void add_transition(STATE *source, char sign, STATE *dest)
{
    if (source->transitions == NULL)
    {

        TRANSITION *transitions = malloc(sizeof(TRANSITION *));
        transitions->c = sign;
        transitions->destination = malloc(sizeof(STATE *));
        transitions->destination = dest;
        source->transitions = transitions;
        source->numberTransitions = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        TRANSITION *transitions = source->transitions;
        int numberTransitions = source->numberTransitions;
        transitions = realloc(transitions, (numberTransitions + 1) * sizeof(TRANSITION *));
        transitions[numberTransitions].c = sign;
        transitions[numberTransitions].destination = dest;
        (source->numberTransitions)++; 
    }
}

void destroy_state(STATE **pp_state)
{
    TRANSITION *transitions = (*pp_state)->transitions;
    // free(transitions->destination);
    // transitions->destination = NULL;
    free(transitions);
    // transitions = NULL;
    // free(pp_state);
    // pp_state = NULL;

}
```

Comment: I'm sure you want to allocate `sizeof(TRANSITION)` since now you're only allocating enough for a pointer, not actually what it points to. And I hope you store the value of `realloc` and don't try to free the original. Hard to say since you don't show the actual code.

Comment: @AlexD i had this before, but then everything is messed up. My chars look like this ▒. Obviously some memory mistake

Comment: When you use `realloc`, your pointer might point to a new place and you might also receive a return value of `NULL` - are you sure you're freeing the correct pointer (not the old address)? Also, you aren't performing **any** error handling in your code, you're ignoring possible contingencies and you obviously ignore compiler warnings... Use compiler warnings, they're there to help!

Comment: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_! And don't use all-uppercase for anything else than macros or _enum-constants_.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I added all.

Comment: As I suspected. You don't store the new pointer from realloc back to `source` so you're freeing already freed memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you fix your allocations, you need to store the return value of `realloc` in `source`. You also need to check that the allocation succeeds.

Currently you leave the old pointer in `source`, so when you try to free the memory the block is already freed and the actual allocated memory is leaked since it is not stored anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to malloc the sizeof(TRANSITION) and not sizeof(TRANSITION*). First is allocating the size of the TRANSITION struct, the second just mallocs the size of a pointer which may be less than the struct size.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to invoke `malloc` like this:

```
T *t = malloc(sizeof(*t));
```

That way your allocation is always the size of the object to which the pointer points.

This is of course equivalent to:

```
T *t = malloc(sizeof(T));
```

but avoids mistakes in the event that the type of `t` changes.